# How btree index column indisunique status TRUE

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Team,
I have verified one of the btree index column indisunique status shows true from pg_index.
there is an primary key  existed on same column.

```
Example: 
create table table1(id integer,name varchar,address varchar);

alter table table1 add constraint id_pk primary key(id);
create index idx_1 on table1 using btree(id);
```

i would like to remove "idx_1" index which is duplicate on this table. but verified idx_1" status  indisunique is true from pg_index.

Can we get know what are the possibilities for  btree index showing indisunique is true?

Answer (score 0):

indisunique means that the index keys have the UNIQUE property with respect to table colums that are indexed. It does not mean that the index is different from the other existing indexes: PostgreSQL allows to create redundant indexes and does not remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i have tested same scenario in local machine but this time btree index status indisunique  shows false. when exactly this indisunique  status will change for btree indexes